# Get city name of marker position

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, jquery-gmap3

I'm using gmap3
I want the a textbox be filled automatically after click on the map by the city name (not latLng or address):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'rightclick', function (event) {
   create_marker(event.latLng);
   var txtCityName = GetCityName(latLng);
});

function GetCityName(){
 ......
};
```

How should I write GetCityName() function?

Is there any better idea?

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here :) try this

```
function GetCityName(latLngs) {
    geocoder.geocode({latLng : latLngs}, reverseGeocodeResult);
}

function reverseGeocodeResult(results, status) {
    currentReverseGeocodeResponse = results;
    if (status == 'OK') {
        if (results.length == 0) {
            alert('None');
        } else {
        alert(results[0].formatted_address);
         }
    } else {
        alert("can't get address");
    }
}
```

you can get more properties ..      JSON.stringify(results[0]);

Comment: results is response, status is == "OK" or more if OK it fine and can get address from results

Answer (score 0):

This is a Reverse Geocoding task.

You need to use the Google geocoding service.

Take a look at the [official examples](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse).

The `result` object returned has an `address_components` attribute. Search the city name inside it.

Comment: I don't need full address, I want only City name. any solution to extract city name from address?

Comment: Updated the answer. Finding the city is now a trivial exercise.